# SDL Web 8: issue with Content service with load balancer server

Tags: web8, load-balancing

Environment Used: SDL web 8+ Linux+ DXA 1.4

We are facing issue while we configure content(Session enabled) service into load balancer using NGINX.

Content service using load balancer IP is working fine, but when we registered this load balancer content service IP to   discovery service, web site throwing “null pointer exception”,

But if we configure/register content service URL with actual server IP, Website works fine.

Please help if you see any such issue, and let me know  if I missed anything while configuring content service with load balancer IP.

Content Service response  with load Balancer server IP as as below:(For testing we only configure one server IP to NGINX)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can they try installing the `service-container-filter-8.x.y-z.jar` which is included in the distribution within `resources\filter`? This filter forwards some requests that some load balancers add back to the service (such as Amazon's ELB).

To install in one of the microservices:

1. Copy JAR to appropriate `<service_name>/lib` folder
2. Reinstall service

Comment: I have tried this, but still the same issue.